# Can't use System.out.println in stream forEach

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am learning flat map and want to print infinite sequence of `integers`.

However, when I try to compile the program it is failing at `System.out.println`:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.of("").flatMap(x -> Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1)).forEach(System.out.println); 
    }
}
```

Can some one help me on this and let me know how can I do this and if possible please check my code for printing infinite sequence of `integers` for problems.

Comment: But what’s the point of `flatMap` here? `Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1) .forEach(System.out.println);` will do…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple:

```
System.out.println
```

is **not** a method reference. You need

```
System.out::println
```

instead. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) for reading. The point is: `flatMap()` expects you something it can "call". And `System.out.println` doesn't denote something that could be called. Simply invalid syntax therefore!

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass a `Consumer` to `forEach`.

You can use a lambda expression:

```
Stream.of("").flatMap(x -> Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1)).forEach(i -> System.out.println (i));
```

or a method reference:

```
Stream.of("").flatMap(x -> Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

P.S., I don't know why you are creating the initial single element `Stream` and then using `flatMap` on it instead of simply creating the infinite `Stream` and running `forEach` on it:

```
Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @Eran- Is the business logic is fine , from your knowledge

Answer (score 3):

You should really watch out infinite streams and `flatmap`, as they are computed eagerly btw, not very trivial to understand:

```
 Stream.of("")
       .flatMap(x -> Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1))
       .limit(1) // added this one
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will print `1` and never finish - the `limit` is un-effective here.